# AutoCompleteTextView (Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, autocompletetextview

I have an AutoCompleteTextView inside a Activity or a Fragment, when I clicked an item in the AutocompleteTextView I am hitting an exception specified in the title.

I try to find where exactly I am hitting the exception but with no luck. The last event that I am hitting is the BeforeTextChanged of the AutocompleteTextView. I know that I need to run some code in the UI thread but I do not know the exact one.

Any advice on how to solve my problem. Thank you in advance.

```
    public AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView;         

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.fragment_camera2_basic);
        autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.autoCompleteTextView1));

        autoCompleteTextView.Threshold = 1;

        autoCompleteTextView.BeforeTextChanged += (sender, e) => {};
    }
```

Comment: you are trying to update data from background thread to ui thread directly, Use runOnUiThread/Handler attached to UI thread to update UI.

Comment: Hi @santoshkumar, can you give me a sample code on how to do so? because I know the concept that I need to use runOnUiThread/Handler but I do not where to apply that. In my example when I clicked an item in my AutoCompleteTextView. Thanks, very much appreciated.

Comment: Add the code so, I can show how

Comment: @G.hakim, I already pasted the code. Just an added info, I also try not using fragment but I still encounter the same error.

Answer (score 0):

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

As suggested in the Comment.You have to move the portion of the background task that updates the UI onto the main thread. There is a simple piece of code for this:

```
RunOnUiThread(() => {
    //UI Thread Code 
});
```

Documentation for [Android.App.Activity.RunOnUiThread Method](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.RunOnUiThread/p/System.Action/)

You need to check if the background thread and the UI thread are mixed together in the code.

Comment: Hi @JuniorJiang, I know that I need to use that code in order to avoid the exception but I do not know exactly where to put it (which is what I am asking). The last event that I catched with my breakpoints is the BeforeTextChanged event. Thanks for your answer btw.

Comment: @jase You can put it in BeforeTextChanged event.If other problem, you can show more code ,I will check it.